# Can't boot Ubuntu 20.04 from USB stick

Tags: boot, 20.04, live-usb, bios

I downloaded the wrong version of Ubuntu (22.04) and successfully installed it on my Lenovo ThinkPad P52, Core i7 laptop. Then I realized that I have wrong version. I downloaded the desktop image file from https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/ (since I wanted Ubuntu 20.04) and I have used Rufus to put it on the USB (the same as during the first installation).

When I plug my USB flash drive into the computer I get this:

[image]

When I press Enter nothing happens. Actually no matter which option I choose nothing happens. The screen blinks and I am still on the same screen. Now I can't boot any OS.

Comment: I think that when you successfully installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS you did everything right. That's the newest LTS version and the best alternative in most cases. Particularly in new computers there can be problems with old versions because some new piece of hardware may need a new driver, that comes [only] with a new version of Ubuntu. Please explain why you want the older version 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Please describe your computer: brand name and model, and also the graphics chip/card: brand name and model. -- Can you use some other computer to create new boot drives?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Comment: The model is lenovo thinkPad P52, core I7 https://www.laptopmag.com/reviews/laptops/lenovo-thinkpad-p52

Comment: I need 20.04 version in order to install Gazebo for competition project. We were told to follow the instructions from here https://github.com/ECC-BFMC/Simulator. So we need version 20.04

Comment: The link says that there is nvidia graphics, and it tells me that you should try with the boot option 'nomodeset' [edit manually in the grub menu] or as an easy alternative select the grub menu alternative 'Ubuntu (safe graphics)'. But your previous experience with 22.04 LTS indicates that it can manage the graphics 'directly' ...

Comment: Another question: Did you try with the original 20.04 LTS from April 2020 or with the currently upgraded 20.04.5 LTS? And did you check the iso file with 'sha256sum'?

Comment: Yeah I tried once again to boot version 22.04 and it works perfectly but 20.04 fails.

Comment: Did you try with the boot option nomodeset yet?

Comment: Could you send me the link of original version? I have downloaded it from here https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/, desktop image link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142797/discussion-between-sudodus-and-luise).

Comment: I am not sure how to use that nomodeset option. In which step should I opt for it? As far as i remember there were not choices while downloading. Could you explain to me how to do in in more detail please?